# How to subtract two images in emgu cv

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have two images, one normal image and another its denoised version. I want to extract noise from an image ,thus need to subtract the two images according to

NOISE = IMAGE - IMAGE(DENOISED)

I am not getting how to subtract two images such that no data will be lost.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

var noiseImg = image - imageDenoised; //operators are overloaded

or:

var noiseImg = image.Sub(imageDenoised);

of course images has to be the same types and the same size

Comment: If you are not getting desired results, also try interchanging the variables.
Instead of ' image - imageDenoised' use 'imageDenoised - image'